Error with Kotlin version for Flutter application
I have the below error with my Flutter application.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             35.5s  

[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.  
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update the version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of C:\Users\mohammed isham\rental_app\android\settings.gradle.

Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19), update C:\Users\mohammed isham\rental_app\android\build.gradle

ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

I have tried these solutions.
Summary of Fixes by AI-generated down here and fixed by me

Updated Kotlin Version:

Changed Kotlin version to 1.7.0 in build.gradle and settings.gradle.


Gradle Configuration:

Updated Gradle wrapper to gradle-8.0.2 in gradle-wrapper.properties.
Ensured the Android Gradle plugin version was compatible.


Dependency Updates:

Updated dependencies in pubspec.yaml.
Ran flutter pub upgrade and flutter pub get.


Java Configuration in Android Studio:

Verified JDK installation (version 11 or higher).
Set JDK path in Android Studio's Project Structure.
Configured JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly.
Restarted Android Studio and invalidated caches.


Clean and Rebuild Project:

Executed flutter clean, followed by flutter build apk --release.



i have even upgraed to the current version of kotlin and tried running it again and again its not working at all and all the ai fixes  i have done

Are you using Android Studio or VS Code?

Recently, I've faced the same issue. I hope you're using the latest version of Flutter and already tried flutter doctor to see if you set your environment correctly.
To directly address your encountered issues, please check this first if you not yet visited this kotlin releases.
But to share my test findings regarding the related case-scenario.
I used the latest version based on the Kotlin releases which is version 2.0.21.
Same with your configuration in build.gradle but change the 1.7.0 to 2.0.21 (i.e., ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.21') and settings.gradle (i.e.,  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false)
and then,
In Visual Studio Code,
I navigated from my current Flutter project directory to Android project directory (i.e., cd android) using the terminal,
and then execute the command:
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version latest

Then I got this

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-bin.zip

from gradle-wrapper.properties file
The primary reason why I did this is to let the IDE choose for me the latest and compatible Gradle distribution.
Then, after those configurations, I execute
flutter clean

or in Android Studio.
rebuild project
You can also use this command,

flutter pub cache repair

in order to be sure that your Flutter package cache is repaired accordingly.
To learn more: Alternative Commands for Cleaning Pub Cache.
CLARIFICATIONS:
It works for me with the above configuration on Flutter 3.24.1 and Dart 3.5.1.
CONCLUSION:
In order for you to observe if you setup your project right, always test the overall process of your app, especially the platform-specific build of the app, and always stay updated on the changelog and release description of the development tools or plugins.
Execute the command flutter doctor -v to check your environment in developing Flutter project. Always refer to the official documentation of Flutter for concrete guidelines.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin
Check the embedded kotlin version that compaitable with your Gradle version. If not upgrade the kotlin version to higher level or latest one then
flutter build clean 
flutter pub get

Run your app again
